# Use .net 4 URL routing to redirect one ASPX page to another based upon query strings?

Tags: asp.net, url-routing

We are restructuring our ASP.Net site a bit and we will need to redirect a lot of page requests to the  new pages.  I was wondering if we could .Net 4's routing mechanism for this.  What will happen is that requests to `OldPage.aspx?i=Parm1` will now go to `NewPage1.aspx` and `OldPage.aspx?i=Parm2` will go to `NewPage2.aspx`.

I know we could go something like this on `OldPage.aspx`:

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
   Response.AddHeader("Location","http://www.new-url.com");
}
```

But could we use the routing to map from one aspx page (and parameter) to another aspx page?  It looks like the RouteTable is more for setting up MVC style routing, not handling redirects from one ASPX page to another.  But, if I could get this to work with the RouteTable, I could remove OldPage.aspx.

```
routes.MapPageRoute(
   "MarketReports",               // Route name
   "Reports/{*i}",  // Route URL
   "~/pageControl2.aspx"      // Web page to handle route
);
```

Comment: Maybe this MSDN article can help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668202(v=vs.90).aspx